# Haskell Datatypes with unknown types

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

For an assignment, the following codes was given

```
-- 2. Index

class Index i where
  findEntry :: Eq k => k -> i k -> Maybe Entry
  empty     :: Eq k => i k
  singleton :: Eq k => k -> Entry -> i k
  (<+>)     :: Eq k => i k -> i k -> i k

-- a. Complete the definition of Assoc
data Assoc k
  = MkAssoc [(k,Entry)]
  deriving (Eq,Show)

-- b. Complete the instance of Index for Assoc
instance Index Assoc where
```

I'm now completely stuck at question 2.b. How do I make the empty and findEntry and the other things? Where does the 'k' come from in index? How come the output of some functions is (i k)? That't not even a type.

Comment: `k` is the `k` typeparameter that binds with `Assoc`, so `k` is the "key" type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `i` in `class Index i` stands for a type constructor of kind `* -> *`. That is, `i` can be something like `Maybe`, `[]`, `IO`. More to the point `i` can also be `Assoc`.

Note that `i` on its own is not a type, but a type constructor, like `Assoc` on its own is not a type. Instead `i k` is a type like `Assoc k` is a type.

The instance you need to write has the following methods to be defined:

```
instance Index Assoc where
  findEntry :: Eq k => k -> Assoc k -> Maybe Entry
  empty     :: Eq k => Assoc k
  singleton :: Eq k => k -> Entry -> Assoc k
  (<+>)     :: Eq k => Assoc k -> Assoc k -> Assoc k
```

You should now be able to fill in the actual definitions.